# generating XML from mysql server for iphone app consumption not working

Tags: php, mysql, xml, ios

I am trying to generate some xml with this php code here... I am trying to use this script for an ios app I am learning from as I go just to figure out how each of the parts fit i.e. (app, php, mysql, xml)

Here is my php script that my ios app is exicuting

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/xml"); 

$username="*****";
$password="***";
$database=" *****";

$testcode=$_REQUEST['usercode']; ////testcode coming from ios app

//connect to database
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password) or die('No DB Connection');
//select database
$db = mysql_select_db('N_codes', $connect) or die("<b>Unable to select specified database</b>");


//Do some stuff here
$query = "SELECT codes FROM codes where id = '$testcode'"; //testcode coming from ios app
$result = mysql_query($query,$connect);


//XML STUFF

$xml_output = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n"; 
$xml_output .= "<entries>\n"; 

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 

$xml_output .= "\t\t<code>" . $row['codes'] . "</code>\n"; 

$xml_output .= "</entries>"; 

echo $xml_output; 


?>
```

This is all that it is producing

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<entries>
        <code></code>
</entries>
```

What I am looking for is a code that should be between  that is in the mysql database and is found by the user supplying a code that is passed to the php script.

Can anyone see whats missing?

Comment: `var_dump()` your `$row['codes']` and see what it returns. its not returning anything, fix that first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a few "potential" problems with the code you provided above.

**1.** Is your table named `codes` and the field you're looking for also `codes`? Your SQL question is looking for a field name codes in a table called codes. It's hard to tell whether or not that's a problem but must rows represent a single field so the plural version of the word "code" makes me believe you made a mistake there.

```
$query = "SELECT code FROM codes where id = '$testcode'";
```

**2.** Try adding a [`die`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) after the query that outputs [`mysql_error][2]` just in case an error occurred.

```
$result = mysql_query($query, $connect) or die(mysql_error($connect));
```

**3.** You should use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) when you use user supplied data in a SQL query.

```
$testcode = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['usercode'], $connect);
```

Comment: oh yep.. silly mistakes.. don't know what I was thinking regarding your first question I should have seen that straight away, My Table name is codes and my field name is code.. so I have fixed that and the other problems you have found.. still not showing anything however.

Comment: @C.Johns - Are you sure that the query is correct? Are you sure that there's a matching row in your database? You should `echo $query;` and see if it's what you're expecting. If you added the `die` after the `mysql_query` as I suggested above and it worked, the query was successful but may not have returned any rows. If you `echo` the query, could you post it here?

Comment: honestly I am not sure what I did I went through and re did the code you supplied me then it worked.. Sorry for the inconvenience.. Thanks very much for the help :)

Comment: @C.Johns - No worried. I'm glad I could help.